# Possible to use Powershell to detect if an HP server has a bad drive?

Tags: powershell, hp, alerts

I'm trying to use Powershell to detect certain hardware failures.

Can Powershell hook into normal HP events/logs/alerts to detect if a drive failed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure. Look up the "hpssacli" utility. You can parse the output.

But the HP management agents eliminate the need to roll-your-own. The server logs this, sends SNMP traps and can email you.

What's your ultimate goal?

Comment: I am looking at some poorly managed servers and need to monitor them without altering configuration, or trap configuration.  Not sure if agents are required for hpssacli or SNMP...

Comment: In attempting to list drive status, the closest I've gotten so far is `controller all show detail` ... haven't figured out how to dump drive status yet

Comment: ... got closer: `controller all show config` which offers drive status.  Would be nice to get serial ...

Comment: Use "ctrl all show config detail"

Comment: Also.. this gives me an XML document that I can use XPATH on to easily get the data (no parsing required) `>hpssacli.exe ctrl all diag file=c:\all2.zip`

Comment: Sounds like you figured it out! ServerFault is a great resource, isn't it?

Comment: This was pretty cool I'll see if I can update with a powershell version ;)