# Is there an automated way to report and open cases with HP for drive failure?

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, drive-failure

I want to take failed drives, send a diagnostic report to HP so I can automatically have the drives shipped to the right location.

I'm considering writing C# code to automatically log in, post a case below, with the drive diagnostics as an attachment. This is possible using some C# magic, but I'd rather have a supported way.

**Question**

- Is there an automatic way to open a case with HP support?

**How to access the HP Service Center**

```
1. Navigate www.hp.com/go/hpsc 
2. Login into your account. (If you dont have one, you can register yourself in the HPSC website). 
3. Click Get help from HP 
4. Click Submit or manage support cases 
5. Select the option ;Submit a case from the left side pane 
6. Enter the product serial number in the Contract or warranty id box. 
7. Click Submit Case and proceed further.
```

Comment: Note to self- this is a follow on to this question; will post the powershell script later... http://serverfault.com/q/714408/51457

Answer (score 3):

I admire your effort to try to automate this process...

However, I don't think it's necessary.

- You don't have to send a diagnostic report to HP to obtain a warranty part.
- The IML log or RAID controller status is good enough to open a support case.

Some things shouldn't be automated. If drive failures are frequent enough to need to automate the case process *(and I'm sure they're not)*, I suggest keeping a few spares on hand and backfilling those spares with the warranty parts from HP.

HP's official answer would be to sign up for their ***[Proactive Care](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/business-services/it-services/proactive-care-services.html)*** service, which will run system scans, predictive tests and automatic support case logging.

Comment: It seems this is an additional thing I need to pay for... that's unfortunate.  EMC uses SRS to phone home with failed disks and that is at no charge.  Because of the cost difference, I think I might pursue writing my own app (I'll open source it)